# Proving $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^{1+\alpha}} \mathrm dt =\frac{\pi}{2 \Gamma(\alpha+1) \sin(\alpha \pi /2)} |a|^\alpha $

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

How to prove the following?
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^{1+\alpha}} \mathrm dt =\frac{\pi}{2 \Gamma(\alpha+1) \sin(\alpha \pi /2)} |a|^\alpha $$

I have tried to do it with some simple methods such as integration by parts or something else and transformed it into calculate $ \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^a\theta\cos^{1-a}\theta d\theta $ . 
Still I can't solve it. Well, I know I'm not gonna solve it through such simple ways I've tried, but I'm indeed not skillful in calculus.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: The integral I believe can be solved using complex Analysis. But real analysis can also be used. Have a look at this video <https://youtu.be/VF7ud3Al6d8>. Use Euler's reflection formula but keep in mind all the convergence criteria and continue. You will get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
$$ L(x^\alpha, t)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{t^{\alpha+1}}, L(\cos(at),x)=\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+a^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{|a|^\alpha\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2})} $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^{1+\alpha}} \mathrm dt\\
&=& \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)} \int_0^\infty L(x^\alpha,t) (1-\cos(at))\mathrm dt\\
&=& \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\int_0^\infty x^\alpha L(1-\cos(at),x)\mathrm dx\\
&=& \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\int_0^\infty x^\alpha(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+a^2})\mathrm dx\\
&=& \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+a^2}\mathrm dx\\
&=& \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\frac{|a|^\alpha\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2})}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2 \Gamma(\alpha+1) \sin(\frac{\alpha \pi}{ 2})} |a|^\alpha.
\end{eqnarray}
Here $L(f(x),t)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(x)$ or
$$ L(f(x),t)=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-tx}dx. $$
One property of Laplace transform is
$$ \int_0^\infty L(f(x),t)g(t)dt=\int_0^\infty f(x)L(g(t),x)dx. $$

Comment: In fact I have transformed the integral into $ \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{\alpha}\theta\cos^{1-\alpha}\theta d\theta $ or your saying $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+a^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{|a|^\alpha\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2})} $. They are the same by letting $ x=a\tan\theta $ . But what bothers me is how to prove this one. Could you plz post the details? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Beta function to prove it.